# Apps using firebase crash after 3-4 days of installing them on a device/simulator (iOS)

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, firebase

I am somewhat new to developing apps for iOS and I have been creating a few demo projects in Xcode. My problem is the following: 
I have been following a few tutorials from Udemy.com and I created an app using firebase, the app works fine for about 3-4 days of use. But after more time passes by, the application does not launch on my device or the simulator. I thought I must have done something wrong when I did the tutorials, so I did them again but the same thing happens after 3-4 days of installing the app. They immediately close after I try to launch them. However, they do work if I rebuild the app on my phone or on the simulator. I do not seem to understand why this happens. has anyone else come across this problem? Or is this a normal thing that happens until you upload the app via the app store? Thank you guys, hope someone here knows. Cheers!

Comment: Can u post ur crashlog on Output screen

Comment: Have u got app store developer account?

Comment: I have only a free developer account. Can this be a reason as to why apps just refuse to run on a device / simulator after a period of time?

Answer (score 0):

in such case you can check your GoogleService-Info.plist file or get idea about what's wrong by check the App terminate reason printed in your output Console.